# Does 'XmlDocument.CreateElement();' ONLY create an element?

Tags: c#, xml, uwp, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

It seems like [someXml.CreateElement("abc");](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.data.xml.dom.xmldocument#Windows_Data_Xml_Dom_XmlDocument_CreateElement_) does only one thing: create the element. It does not add it as a child as I expected, nor does it seem to do anything else.

But that doesn't make much sense. Why create an element with an instance method instead of with a static method? That would indicate that it *does* have some relationship to the instance. But I couldn't find anything and hence my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The remarks in Microsoft's Documentation mentions that default attributes are created on the returned object. Namespaces come to mind as they may be automatically applied to the new element based on the XmlDocument's schema/defaults.

It also states that it must be manually added to the desired parent node.

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw1ys7w6(v=vs.110).aspx

> Note that the instance returned implements the XmlElement interface, so default attributes would be created directly on the returned object.
>
> Although this method creates the new object in the context of the document, it does not automatically add the new object to the document tree. To add the new object, you must explicitly call one of the node insert methods.

Comment: Though you're referring to a different framework (see the link I supplied in the question), I think your answer regarding the namespace may be correct.

Comment: Sorry about that - I didn't notice it was linked to a different page. I believe DOM should be similar although I unfortunately couldn't find a better reference on Microsoft's site.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason that the method doesn't automatically add the element as a child like you were expecting is because there would be no way to know where the element should be added. The document could have many children and there is nothing to specify which element the created element should be added to. It can't just add it by default to the root element, because there's a good chance that isn't always going to be the desired location.

As previously mentioned, the perks of having it be an instance method rather than a static method would be to automatically create the default attributes (such as namespace) on the newly created element. That way once it is created it should just need to be added to the proper location in the document.